# Transfer from Fiumicino Aeroporto to the City Center

Tags: airport-transfer, taxis, rome

There are several possibilities to get from the airport to the city center in Rome, unless you are arriving after 11 PM. After this time there are only taxis and dedicated "luxury transfer cars" available. Is that right?

I found [this](http://www.worldtaximeter.com/rome) website  and it says that there is a fixed fee of 40 Euros to get from Fiumicino Aeroporto to Roma Termini... Is that reasonable and/or dependable? How can I identify official taxis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taxis in Rome are more expensives than in other European capitals. For example, a short travel (10 minutes) in the city center cost us 10 euros. As you said, the airports have fixed fees.

Taxis are white and have a license number in both sides and inside. Also, obviouslly, they have the word "taxi". It's very important that you never take a taxi from someone that offer you to get you to the city, because be sure that this is not an official taxi (a real taxi driver will never do that).

Also, it is convenient that you ask the driver about the price before hop on the taxi.

Anyway, be careful also with the official taxis. I've heard histories about scams even from this kind of taxis. If you have any problem, take the taxi license and the car plate number.